# how to query sql cross-reference table

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-reference

i am novice at SQL and have problems hope you can help me :

mysql5

**table TRAINING_REQUESTS**

```
+------------+--------+
|    ID_TR   |  FIELD |
+------------+--------+
|      ...   |   ..   |
|      254   |   ..   |
|      ...   |   ..   |
|      286   |   ..   |
|      ...   |   ..   |
|      401   |   ..   |
|      ...   |   ..   |
|      405   |   ..   |
|      406   |   ..   |
|      ...   |   ..   |
+------------+--------+
```

**table PLANNING_REQUESTS**

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| ID_PR    | ID_TR    |  TRAINER |
+----------+----------+----------+
|      ... | ...      | ...      |
|      475 | 254      |  NULL    |
|      476 | 254      |  NULL    |
|      477 | 254      |  NULL    |
|      478 | 286      |  NULL    |
|      479 | 286      |  FREE    |
|      480 | 286      |  FREE    |
|      481 | 401      |  FREE    |
|      482 | 401      |  1       |
|      483 | 401      |  FREE    |
|      484 | 405      |  NULL    |
|      485 | 405      |  1       |
|      486 | 405      |  5       |
|      487 | 405      |  FREE    |
|      488 | 406      |  1       |
|      489 | 406      |  5       |
|      490 | 406      |  5       |
|      491 | 406      |  2       |
|      ... | ...      |  ...     |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I needs 3 things :

**Expected result**

Constraint : all the training_requests (ID_TR) that are not ok , it means 
(>> ALL TRAINING REQUESTS(ID_TR) that have ALL ASSIGNED PLANNING REQUESTS(ID_PR) 
WITH TRAINER EQUALS (NULL OR FREE)

```
+------------+-------+
|    ID_TR   | field |
+------------+-------+
|      254   |   ..  |
|      286   |   ..  |
+------------+-------+
```

Constraint : all the training_requests (ID_TR) that are nearly ok, it means 
(>> ALL TRAINING REQUESTS(ID_TR) that have ALL ASSIGNED PLANNING REQUESTS(ID_PR) 
WITH TRAINER AT LEAST ONE TIME DIFFERENT FROM (NULL OR FREE) 
AND NOT ALL WITH TRAINER ASSIGNED (DIFFERENT FROM NULL OR FREE)

```
+------------+-------+
|    ID_TR   | FIELD |
+------------+-------+
|      405   |   ..  |
+------------+-------+
```

Constraint : all the training_requests that are not ok and nearly ok

```
+------------+------+
|    ID_TR   |FIELD |
+------------+------+
|      405   |  ..  |
|      254   |  ..  |
|      286   |  ..  |
+------------+------+
```

thx for all !

Comment: Have you tried to write your queries?

Comment: ofc i tried but im beginner at sql and i dont know how to query cross reference table

Comment: Do you know what `JOIN` is? Or `EXISTS`?

Comment: yes i know ? like inner join

Comment: What about `sub-queries` in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You have very basic tasks here. Quite suitable for beginners.

Comment: and how can i have both request in only one ? all the training_requests that are not ok and nearly ok should i use union ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM training_requests tr 
JOIN planning_requests pr ON tr.ID_TR = pr.ID_TR
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM planning_requests pr WHERE pr.trainer IS NULL) doesnt works

Comment: I tried EXISTS JOIN AND SUBQUERIES but it doesnt works : SELECT * FROM training_requests tr JOIN planning_requests pr ON tr.ID_TR = pr.ID_TR
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM planning_requests pr WHERE pr.trainer IS NULL) i would like to check if a group of planning request for the SAME training request is NULL not only one

Comment: i found the first needs:

>SELECT tr.ID_TR,tr.field FROM planning_requests pr
    INNER JOIN training_requests tr
    ON tr.ID_TR = pr.ID_TR
    WHERE pr.ID_TR NOT IN (
 SELECT cpr.ID_TR FROM planning_requests cpr 
 WHERE trainer IS NOT NULL 
 AND trainer <> 'FREE' )
    GROUP BY ID_TR


but now i need with at least one different from NULL

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post updates as answers (unless you actually solve your issue and would like to post the answer you discovered).

Comment: Have you looked at my answer yet? Click on Fiddle link and you can see how it works.  Obviously there are other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT tr.ID_TR,tr.field 
    FROM planning_requests pr 
    INNER JOIN training_requests tr 
    ON tr.ID_TR = pr.ID_TR 
    WHERE pr.ID_TR NOT IN 
      (
      SELECT cpr.ID_TR 
      FROM planning_requests cpr 
      WHERE trainer IS NOT NULL AND trainer <> 'FREE' 
      ) 
    GROUP BY ID_TR
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done the following (possibly inefficient) way:

**#1** (*not OK*)

```
SELECT tr.*
FROM TRAINING_REQUESTS tr
JOIN PLANNING_REQUESTS pr ON tr.id_tr = pr.id_tr
GROUP BY pr.id_tr
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN pr.trainer IS NULL or pr.trainer = 'FREE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
;
```

**#2** (*nearly OK*)

```
SELECT tr.*
FROM TRAINING_REQUESTS tr
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM PLANNING_REQUESTS pr 
              WHERE tr.id_tr = pr.id_tr 
              AND pr.trainer IS NOT NULL AND pr.trainer <> 'FREE') 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM PLANNING_REQUESTS pr 
              WHERE tr.id_tr = pr.id_tr 
              AND (pr.trainer IS NULL OR pr.trainer = 'FREE'))        
;
```

**#3**

```
    SELECT tr.*
    FROM TRAINING_REQUESTS tr
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM PLANNING_REQUESTS pr 
                  WHERE tr.id_tr = pr.id_tr 
                  AND (pr.trainer IS NULL OR pr.trainer = 'FREE'))        
;
```

Here's [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84cf2/23) with the results.

Please note that my results in #2 (and, therefore, #3) are different from yours as they include **401**.